# Cannot use post on NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express

So I'm trying to insert 3 strings from postman to my mongo database using the api localhost:3000/api/comment/

my database is on `mongodb://localhost:27017/commentbox`

and my server.js contains

```
var express = require('express');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var config = require('./config');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(morgan('dev'));

var api = require("./app/routes/api")(app, express);

api.use('/api', api);

app.get('*',(req, res)=>{
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/views/index.html');
});

mongoose.connect(config.database, { useNewUrlParser: true },(err)=>{
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }else{
        console.log('Connected to DB');
    }
});



app.listen(config.port, (err) =>{ 
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }else{
        console.log('Listening on port:'+ config.port);
    }
});
```

and this is the code for my api.js

```
var User = require('../models/user');


module.exports = function(app,express){

    var api = express.Router();

    api.post('/comment', function(req,res){
        var user = new User({
            name: req.body.name,
            comment: req.body.comment,
            date: req.body.date
        });

        user.save(function(err){
            if(err){
                res.send(err);
                return;
            }

            res.json({ message: "User has commented"});
        });
    });

    return api;
}
```

when I try to post on postman with name, comment, date (btw this are 3 strings at the moment) I always got error 404

what should be the problem? I have followed the guide thoroughly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace this line

```
api.use('/api', api);
```

With this

```
app.use(‘/api’, api);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try switching localhost to 127.0.0.1, or http://[::1]:3000

It looks like there is a common report of this issue with 'localhost' specifically: https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/2214

Comment: Is 'comment' in the root?

Answer (score -1):

I Think You api.js module was wrong. please remove **return api**

Comment: api.use('/api', api);
    ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'use' of undefin
    at Object.<anonymous> (A:\Project\Mean\Comme
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12) new error pops out

Comment: remove api.use('/api', api); and add app.use('/api', api);
Best practice keep module require your server.js very begin of the file